# Import data .csv into couchdb

Tags: couchdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import CSV/TSV data to Couch DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238387/how-to-import-csv-tsv-data-to-couch-db)

I have a question about how can I put into couchdb database a .csv data file. Because I'm trying test the tpch test on nosql database.

My target is to try to execute the tpc-h test (if it possibile and in the limit of possibility) because I should compare the sql like schema versus Nosql; I understand that the comparison is not exact but I would know and demostrate(in my thesis) when is better nosql schema and why there are an interests from this type of database.

For create this comparison I need to find a way, after create a couchdb document, for load a big data files saved into csv data file. Someone can help me?

To be more precise (hopefully) I  summarize the steps:

- create a couchddb  database as like a document
- import .csv data file into a document (cosi da popolare il database) is possible? How?
- try model and to execute the tpc-h queries

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB only stores JSON documents. So you need to convert CSV to individual JSON documents and then POST then post normaly.

I find something can be usefull : [import data to couchdb](http://skyl.org/log/post/littlemog/2009/11/dumping-data-to-couchdb/)