# How do i import CSV files into couchdb update existing data, insert new records, delete old records

Tags: php, bash, shell, couchdb, sh

What I'm trying to do is import a CSV or TSV file into couchdb update records that have changes to them, remove records (or mark as not active) that are no longer in the csv file, and insert new records into the database.  I need to keep all the revision data to show fluctuations in values.  Can someone help me with this?

I've seen: [How to import CSV/TSV data to Couch DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238387/how-to-import-csv-tsv-data-to-couch-db)

This helps get the initial data into couchdb but doesn't help with the insert/update/delete portion of my question.

Comment: @Brad, when you want answers, please interact actively.

Comment: man, I'm really not liking stackoverflow anymore...  close perfectly good questions that I "KNOW" many people out there want to know.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I was at work just got off work since I asked the question and you want me to interact actively.  It's only been 14 hours!

Comment: Dude, it wasn't even an hour, you left off orphaned!